# Python как округлить число с дробной частью в меньшую сторону с заданным количеством знаков в дробной части?

Tags: python, математика

Есть переменная, в которой число с дробной частью

```
value: '0.00051057'
```

Задача в том, чтобы получить число, в дробной части которого останется 6 знаков и округлить дробную часть в меньшую сторону

Почитал про math.ceil, ‎math.floor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так не устроит?

```
x = 0.00051057
x = int(x * 1000000)/1000000
print(x);
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло